# Exception Handling on Message Driven Bean in Java

Tags: ejb-3.1, websphere-8, message-driven-bean

I have created a MDB to listen to the messages on a Queue.
Question- I want to stop the MDB or the application if it fails more than 10 times with the same exception.
I am using EJB 3.1 and Queues,AS is created on IBM WebSphere Console.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the sections on "Automatically stop endpoints on repeated message failure" and "Sequential failed message threshold" and  on the following knowledge center page (and similar sections following this for MQ),
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cmb_trans.html

It looks like it should be possible to set a threshold of 10 consecutive failures, but I don't  see anything about requiring it to be the same exception.